# Service requirements from Telecom API

Tags: java, web-services, load-testing, performance-testing, telecommunication

I created a service or application (whatever you call it ;)) which use Location and SMS REST API which are provided by Telecom. I hope that i do not have to explain what that APIs do, but  first is obtaining a mobile phone location and second one is sending SMS to mobile phone.

I was wondering which, mainly in telecommunication way, parameters are used to describe parameters which are important for those APIs. I think it will be :

-response time, maintain services under heavy load, service delay, maybe CAPS (Call per second).

That's why i would like to ask, what more it can be tested with those APIs...to combine with the requirements of the telecom

Answer (score 0):

If you use "REST API" it means that you use high level API and talk with the network through gateways which take off most problems.

But if you talk with SMSC or USSDC directly via SMPP, then the rule number one is "send acknowledge packets(responds) as soon as possible", or it will resend you SMS again. USSDС will hold signal link till you send answer to client. And so on. But it isn't your case... you use gateways that keep network in safety.

Location services are not so capricious.